# Cors error - ngrok & express & axios issue when trying to make POST request to the server

Tags: express, axios, cors, ngrok

I am experiencing an issue when trying to make POST request to the server.
both frontend and backend are ngrok hosting.

this is the POST request:

```
  export async function createTest(test: any) {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post(
          `${backendDomain}/test`,
           {id: test, name: 'test'},
          {
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            },
          }
        )
        const newTest = res.data
        return newTest 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
```

this is the backendDomain: `https://sd21-23-221-223-216.ngrok.io`

Backend:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://dz23-12-256-124-663.eu.ngrok.io",
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'],
  credentials: true,
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sd21-23-221-223-216.ngrok.io/test' from origin 'https://dz23-12-256-124-663.eu.ngrok.io' has been blocked by CORS policy:
```

Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

More wierd is that I also have GET request which sometimes work and sometimes not.

any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this header param `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` with any value

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://5120-143-202-253-244.eu.ngrok.io/api',
  type: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "ngrok-skip-browser-warning":"any"
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```